# Limit number of downloads in AWS S3

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

I have a Wordpress website and want to store all my media files in an s3 bucket. However, if I set all the bucket files for public read access, if someone does a whole lot of requests on purpose, they could lead my company to bankruptcy, as the traffic bills from AWS would increase.
Is there a solution? Maybe signed URLs?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options you can take.

You could add a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of your S3 bucket, and enable caching which at very minimum is going to reduce the pricing you pay once the object is cached (not by much), especially when you also [enable auto compression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html) on a distribution.

- S3 charges `$0.09 per GB` after your first GB upto the first 10TB
- CloudFront charges `$0.085 per GB` upto 10TB, but remember that auto compression will reduce asset size.

The big advantage though, is that you gain access to [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) which can be attached to your CloudFront distribution, with support for [rate limiting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-get-started-rate-based-rules.html) to specifically stop targeted attacks against your infrastructure.

In addition CloudFront benefits from the built in feature set of [AWS Shield Standard](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) (at no cost) which actively mitigates against DDoS attacks on your infrastructure.

If your assets are behind a paywall or require authentication you could enhance the security by enabling [signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) when a user logs in to enable access to the assets, other CloudFront will reject the requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a Cloudfront distribution in front of your S3 bucket. AWS Cloudfront integrate [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/shield/) which protect you againt DDoS attack